Model suggestion for AI based scaling
We are exploring the idea of scaling elements within a UI container based on the given size.
The container is represented by a json object, for example:
{
   "Size":"small",
   "Elements":[
      {
         "type":"image",
         "x":348,
         "y":36,
         "width":607,
         "height":201
      },
      {
         "type":"text",
         "x":45,
         "y":100,
         "width":100,
         "height":104
      }
   ]
}

We would have similar JSON for sizes medium and large with adjusted x,y coordinates and width and height for each element in the JSON.
Currently, these adjustments are handled by a rule-based algorithm which doesn't work the best sometimes and we have to manually adjust the coordinates or the dimensions.
Is there any ML model that can cater this problem efficiently and suggest the coordinates and dimensions given we train it with enough data?
